# How to prevent or disable the event handling of a button's click depending on a text-input's value?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, event-handling, dom-events

I have a 'onChange' event on a text field, that check some condition.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#txt').on('change', (ev) => {

    if ($(ev.target).val() == "stop") {                     
      console.warn("Wrong condition, I want to avoid the click event on button");
      alert("Wrong condition, no click on button");                     
    } else {
      console.log("Condition OK!");
    }                   
  });

  $('#btn').on('click', (e) => {                    
    console.log("Button pressed");                  
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">                
  <input id="txt"/>
  <button id="btn">Click me</button>
</div>
```

What I like to have is that, when I type 'stop' on the field and then click the button, the button's click triggers the onChange and the onChange event should prevent the click event execution.
With the alert() this works, but I want it works without the alert() too.
Is it possible?

Comment: How does the click on the buttons triggers the onchange event?

Comment: @ThisGuy I forgot to say that change and click handler have to work separately, in the real scenario the change event validate and format the input text value, while the click submit values to server. My problem is when the onChange is triggered by the click on button, and only in this case I need to have the possibility to avoid the click event

Comment: @flappix this is the natural behaviour for Chrome, when the input text lost focus (and the value is changed) the change event is trigger, in this case he click event cause the lost focus that triggers the change event

Comment: Could'nt you just drop the onchange event handler and only check in the click event if the text input value is ```stop``` ? If the button is part of a form you can use the onsubmit event handler and return ```false``` in case the text is not valid. Something like this https://jsfiddle.net/kevtz1bj/

Comment: @M.Prati ... Regarding the sole remaining approach / solutions are there any questions left?

Comment: @M.Prati ... Does the OP still participate in this thread?

Answer (score 0):

Switching the text-field and button validation-handling from a `'change'` to an `'input'` event does support a brute force approach which disables/enables the button upon the OP's condition. The latter btw got changed as well from the value having to equal `'stop'` to a value that just has to contain/include the substring `'stop'` regardless of its letter-casing.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // ... switching from 'change' to 'input' event
  //     does support the following brute force approach ...
  $('#txt').on('input', (ev) => {

    if ($(ev.target).val().toLowerCase().includes("stop")) {                     
      // "Wrong condition, I want to avoid the click event on button"

      // ... disabling the button is one possible way ...
      $('#btn')[0].disabled = true;
    } else {
      $('#btn')[0].disabled = false;
    }                   
  });

  $('#btn').on('click', (e) => {                    
    console.log("Button pressed");                  
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">                
  <input id="txt"/>
  <button id="btn">Click me</button>
</div>
```

A proper generic implementation of the above approach and code into vanilla JS then might look as follows ...

```js
function handleComponentButtonClick(evt) {
  const elmButton = evt.currentTarget;
  const elmInput = elmButton.previousElementSibling;

  console.log({ currentClickRelatedValue: elmInput.value });
}
function handleComponentButtonState(evt) {
  const elmInput = evt.currentTarget;
  const elmButton = elmInput.nextElementSibling;

  elmButton.disabled = elmInput.value.toLowerCase().includes('stop');
}

function enableInputAndButtonComponentBehavior(elmButton) {
  const elmInput = elmButton.previousElementSibling;

  elmInput
    .addEventListener('input', handleComponentButtonState);
  elmButton
    .addEventListener('click', handleComponentButtonClick);
}

function main() {
  document
    .querySelectorAll('.container [type="text"] + button')
    .forEach(enableInputAndButtonComponentBehavior);
}
main();
```

```css
.container { float: left; margin: 0 20px; }
```

```html
<div class="container">                
  <input type="text" />
  <button>Click me</button>
</div>

<div class="container">                
  <input type="text" />
  <button>Click me</button>
</div>
```